# How can I view the full exception thrown by a script in the shell?

Tags: shell, shell-script, pipe, exceptions

When I'm running my ruby script, I'm getting an exception. However, since I'm running Ubuntu in VMware Fusion, I can't resize my terminal window so I can't see the whole excecption.

How can I view the whole thing?

I've tried

```
ruby script.rb > out.txt
```

and

```
ruby script.rb | more
```

but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix, normal program output is usually written to the *stdout* stream and errors go to *stderr*. (Input is called *stdin*.)

- In sh/bash shells (also in Windows cmd.exe), use **`2>`** to redirect *stderr*:

  ```
  ruby script.rb >out.txt 2>err.txt
  ```

  To point both to the same place, `2>&1` can be used:

  ```
  ruby script.rb >out.txt 2>&1 # (order matters)
  ```

  ```
  ruby script.rb 2>&1 | more
  ```
- In bash, use `>&` to redirect both at once:

  ```
  ruby script.rb >& out.txt
  ```

  ```
  ruby script.rb |& more
  ```

---

In most Linux terminals you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to scroll the text.